# How can I get the touch screen working on a motion computing m1400

Tags: tablet

I picked up a motion computing m1400 for cheap and was successful in getting 11.04 installed on it but have run into trouble getting the touch screen to work. This is one of the older tablet pcs that need a special pen for the touch screen. There are instructions out there for older versions of Ubuntu but they usually rely on a package called wacom-tools that is no longer in the repos. Is there any support for these old tablets or has time passed them by?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the xserver-xorg-input-wacom driver is installed, you should be able to use xinput. On my Motion tablet (LE-1600), to get the right click working it is:

`xinput set-button-map "Serial Wacom Tablet" 1 3 2`

I just put that as a start-up command (using 10.04 LTS) when logging in.

I don't know much about xinput, but [the man page has a bunch of info](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man1/xinput.1.html)

(use `xinput list` to figure out what your wacom device is called)